# Remove duplicates based on two columns SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates, amazon-redshift, rownum

Hi everyone,

I need to remove duplicates based on two columns.
ANON ID and USER ID. They have a many to many relationship.
i.e. an anon id can have several user id's and vice versa. I need to leave just one instance. Anywhere anon id OR user id appears as a duplicate, this needs to be removed.

Sample data

[image]

Only rows 1, 4, 6, 7 should remain.

I know I can use rownum() and delete where rownum > 1 for ONE duplicate column. However in this case I need to remove any row where EITHER ANON id or USER ID has already appeared.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you are looking for `group by` on `AnonId` and `UserId`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen as I mentioned only rows 1,4,6,7 should remain

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @Jimmy a simply group by wont work. row 8 and 12 are duplicates because they both have user id of 9. a group by on anon Id and user id would not flag these two rows as duplicates

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen amazon redshift

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two rownum() functions and delete based on either results. If for some reason you can't have 2 rownum functions in one query, you can use dense_rank too.